# How to work with rails pusher using js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried some basic pusher in web while i creating a private channel i could not trigger?

so this is the way i triggered in my company_controller.rb

```
Pusher.trigger_async('private-'+token, 'post_list',
                               { 
                                 message: 'New post',
                               })
```

and while i run get api/post from postman
I get this

```
{

  "headers": [],
  "body": [],
  "async_thread": {},
  "queue": {}

}
```

Please let me know how to so a basic setup for pusher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read through the [documentation](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-ruby). There you can see to get started, you can use `Pusher.trigger('private-'+token, 'toBeTriggered')` from the Ruby side. Assuming you have `pusher.min.js` in your `vendor/assets/javascript` and the line `//= require pusher.min.js` in your `application.js`, you should be able to create a channel and bind an event to it, from the front end point of view like so:

```
var channel = pusherInstance.subscribe('private-'+ token);
channel.bind('toBeTriggered', function(data) {
    alert('I got triggered');
}
```

where the `pusherInstance` is for instance, defined in a javascript like so:

```
var pusherInstance = new Pusher("your pusher key")`
```

Hope that gets you going >)

Comment: How you will subscribe a private channel? I need that perfect syntax with explanation please

Comment: Before I asking this question I'm trying this but it is not working

Comment: Can you please post your Gemfile, relevant Javascript files and the Ruby file that is triggering the javascript?